# App crashes with two custom 'UITableViewCell' in the same 'UITableView'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I have a 'UITableView' which should be loaded with one Custom 'UITableViewCell'. When the user touch one of the cells, the touched cell is replaced by another custom cell, with a extra Label of information.

However, the app is crashing when the user touch the cell. It's raising the following exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[simplefiedCell cellInfo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5b2f3d950'

Where is my code for `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
if(indexPath.row == self.selectedCell) {

    regularCell *cell = (regularCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID1];

    [cell.cellInfo setText:@"Some temporally text to test this code"];


    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"regularCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;

}else{

    simplefiedCell *cell = (simplefiedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID2];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"simplefiedCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text1"];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text2"];
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text3"];
            break;
        case 3:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text4"];
            break;
        case 4:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text5"];
            break;
        case 5:
            [cell.cellTopic setText:@"Text6"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And where the simple code that I use inside `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if (indexPath.row == self.selectedCell)
    self.selectedCell = -1;
else
    self.selectedCell = indexPath.row;

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Does anyone know what is going on? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I suspect that the problem is not in the code you've pasted above.  Chances are either:

- You accidentally registered the simplifiedCell NIB for cellID1 and are getting a simplified cell class when you're expecting a regular cell.
- The values of cellID1 and cellID2 are the same, causing the later registration to win.
- You specified the wrong custom class in the regularCell XIB and are actually instantiating the simplifiedCell class.

If none of those three is the case, then I would suggest searching for the simplified cell class's name—first in the XIB xml file, then in the code—and wherever you find it, ask yourself if it should really be the regular class in that spot instead.  Presumably one of them should be.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are right: I accidentally registered the simplifiedCell NIB for cellID1.

Comment: BTW, IIRC, the dequeue method should only return nil if either A. you register nil as the NIB for an identifier or B. you're thoroughly out of memory to the point that malloc() is failing to create an object, at which point you're going to crash anyway.  So you can probably dispense with those checks.

Comment: I'm not sure why but, apparently it is return nil here. I've double check the identifiers in NIB and they are registered as correctly. I don't think lack of memory is the problem here.

Comment: It is possible that I'm remembering wrong, but the documentation also says that it shouldn't return nil if you registered a class for that reuse identifier.  I think it would definitely be worth looking into that further, because something else may be wrong, like your custom class not being a subclass of an actual cell, or not implementing some required method or something.  (I'm not a table view expert by any means, though, so take that with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Both custom classes were declared as a subclass of UITableViewCell. In fact, all they do is overwrite '(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier'. I'm not sure if they need to implement any other method. But I am definitely looking further into that. Thank you again!